# cant login amazion ec2 created with AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws

I can't log in my aws ec2 instances with password

here ill explain what I did

1. create new aws ec2 instances (remove key login and enable password login)
2. create image
3. again create new instances with previously created AMI

then I try to login via ssh new create instances but I can't how can I log in? (in new instances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Set the SAME MAC address of the ethernet card, in both places in the file. Adjust the eth0 if required.

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6
      set-name: eth0
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      macaddress: 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6
      interfaces:
        - eth0
```

---

**Note**: You may need to create `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

---

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot` # mandatory

See https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/faq.html